# Dúvida usando o FireDac com TClienteDatSet

Tags: delphi

Estou usando estes componentes mais estou tendo o seguinte erro ao tentar abri o ClientDataSet.

Gera o erro:

> Access violation at address 50FCDC6F in module 'dsnap230.bpl'. Read of
>   address 00000000.
>
> TDFConnection para conexão ao banco
>
> TDFQuery com a consulta sql de uma tabela para teste
>
> TDataSetProvider com a propriedade DataSet ligado ao TDFQuery,
>   ativando as propriedades poAllowCommandText é poPropogateChanges
>
> TClienteDatSet ligado ao TDataSetProvider na propriedade ProviderName

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dê mais detalhes sobre a sua pergunta, Delphi qual versão? xe2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... Qual banco de dados? ... O banco de dados é externo ou interno?? O erro esta dando antes de compilado,durante ou depois?? Qual a estrutura android,windows ou ios? Você testou a conexão manual pelo componente para verificar se a conexão com o banco está funcional??

Answer (score 0):

adicione  '`MidasLib`' ao uses  aonde vc tiver seu `ClientDataset` para fazer a conexão remota com o `dataSetProvider`.

Comment: Isso eu já tinha feito, é não resolve o problema

Comment: As informações estão incompletas: Você consegue abrir o FDConnection? Você consegue abrir a FDQuery sem o DataSetProvider+ClientDataSet? Faça os testes por componente. 1) FDConnection, 2) FDConnection + FDQuery, 3) FDConnection + FDQuery + (DataSetProvider, ClientDataSet). Assim você saberá onde está o erro. Eu utilizo o FireDac e nunca ocorreu este erro, e não posso ajudá-lo porque você não colocou as propriedades de conexão que está utilizando, nem o conteúdo SQL da inserido na query. Desta forma, o problema pode estar desde o FDConnection até as propriedades do ClientDataSet.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o componente FDMemTable no lugar do ClientDataSet e no lugar de usar o DataSetProvider use o .Data da FDQuery e .Data do MemTable para passar o conteúdo. Depois que comecei a fazer isso não tive mais dor de cabeça com ClientDataSet. Exemplo:

```
  if (FDQuery.Active) then
    FDQuery.Close;
  FDQuery.SQL.Clear;
  FDQuery.SQL.Add('SELECT CAMPO FROM TABELA');
  FDQuery.Open;
  FDMemTable.Data := FDQuery.Data;
```